# How can I modify the output of ASP.NET Repeater to replace text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a complete newbie at ASP.NET stuff, so please forgive if this is an easy question. I have a repeater table with three columns that is pulling values from a dataset to get populated. Here is the webpage code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<asp:Repeater ID="assetTypeDisplay" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
   <td>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "primary_asset") %>
   </td>
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
</tr>
<tr>
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</tr>
</table>
```

The `primary_asset` column is a bit value, I want it not to return True/False I want it to show "Primary Asset" on the webpage in the table if true, and nothing if it's false. There's another column called "Secondary Asset" that I also want to do the same. There's a third column `additional_asset_type` that is an integer and based on the value will determine what additional values should show up in this table.

Here is my code behind

```
assetTypeDataset = AssetController.GetAssetTypeByApplicationID(Convert.ToInt32(AppID));
if (assetTypeDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   assetTypeDisplay.DataSource = assetTypeDataset.Tables[0];
   assetTypeDisplay.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(assetTypeDisplay_ItemDataBound);
   assetTypeDisplay.DataBind();
}

protected int assetTypeCounter = 0;
protected int assetTypeColumnCount = 3;

private void assetTypeDisplay_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator)
      if ((++assetTypeCounter % assetTypeColumnCount) != 0)
         e.Item.Visible = false;
}
```

What do I need to change so instead of just showing the single value it will show the values from everything? I feel like on the webpage it should be something like `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "assetTypes") %>` so it can show Primary, Secondary, and all the other types, but that has to be a reference to the column name.

Final result should look like this for an application with just primary asset:

```
| Primary Asset |------------|
```

This if it's just a secondary asset:

```
|---------------| Secondary Asset |
```

And this if it's both:

```
| Primary Asset | Secondary Asset |
```

Just using the tables for clarity, it does not however need to be in any specific table format, as long as it shows and hides the values like that and isn't just showing me `| False | True |` and so on. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "primary_asset")) == true ? "Primary Asset" : "------" %>
```

Same for Secondary Assets,

```
<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "secondary_asset")) == true ? "Secondary Asset" : "------" %>
```

Updated code to show 2 separate columns for asset types:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <asp:Repeater ID="assetTypeDisplay" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
             <td>
                <%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "primary_asset")) == true ? "Primary Asset" : "------" %>
             </td>
             <td>
                <%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "secondary_asset")) == true ? "Secondary Asset" : "------" %>
             </td>
          </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            </tr>
            <tr>
       </SeparatorTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for changing the output. But how can I make it so this will add the additional asset types in the two column format? I feel like the ItemTemplate tag should contain just a single value that is looped for each asset type, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since I've used webforms, but you can try this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "primary_asset")?"Primary Asset":"" %>
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this, but the exact syntax eludes me:

```
<%# GetAssetType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "primary_asset")) %>
```

Then create a function "GetAssetType" that examines the parameter(s) you pass in and returns the correct value.  You can even pass in Container.DataItem if you so choose.